# Increase internal size of light switch box

Tags: lighting, wiring

I have a light switch that I'm adding a smart relay to.
The box in the wall is the regular 1 gang size but it's too small to have the wiring, relay and the switch itself.
Is there such a way to use a 2 gang size box in the wall but only have the actual switch screwed into one.
Essentially having the plaster covering half the box.
Has anyone done anything like this before?

I've seen you can get plates to cover the box, but I'm looking to keep the extra space behind the plaster and out of sight.

I cannot increase the depth and do not want to extend out from the wall. The wiring also cannot be modified any further to allow for more space.

Comment: This sounds like a job for diy.stackexchange.com.  I don't think that what you're contemplating is a good idea, though -- relays wear out, so you want to make sure that you have a solution that will allow for easy access.  A double-gang box with a blanked-off cover plate will do that.

Comment: the box must have an easily removable cover